# Comb space has no simply connected cover

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm having trouble solving the following exercise in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology(1.3 #5):

"Let $X$ be the subspace of $R^2$ consisting of the four sides of the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ together with the segments of the vertical lines $x=\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\ldots$ inside the square. Show that for every covering space $\tilde{X}\to X$ there is some neighbourhood of the left edge of $X$ that lifts homeomorphically to $\tilde{X}$. Deduce that $X$ has no simply-connected cover."

I tried piecing together open sets in $\tilde{X}$ which were homeomorphic to open square shaped $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods of points in the left edge of $X$, but I couldn't glue them together coherently.

My second idea was to use the path lifting property to lift the left edge, but I couldn't extend it to a lift of an open neighbourhood of the left edge.

**Edit**: Some more detail on my first attempt:

Suppose I have two open squares $U_1$ and $U_2$ in $X$ (containing the left edge) with nonempty intersection, and that have preimages $\coprod_i U_{1,i}$ and $\coprod_j U_{2,j}$ with each piece of that mapping homeomorphically onto $U_1$ and $U_2$ respectively.

Suppose I've chosen a specific $U_{1,i}$, and I want to choose a specific $U_{2,j}$ so that their union maps homeomorphically to $U_1$ union $U_2$. Such a choice can be specified by a point in the chosen $U_{1,i}$ that maps into $U_2$, but for each such point, there could be a different choice of $j$.

My intution tells me that to make this choice, one needs to appeal to the bad local nature of the left edge of $X$, (so that you're certain to get some of the vertical lines inside of the desired open set) but I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: I think this should come directly from the definition of a covering space, where you've got that the projection map has to be a local homeomorphism.  And probably you'll need to use that the interval is compact, to extract a finite subcover of a cover whose open sets all lift homeomorphically.

Comment: why can't you glue the open squares coherently? I think this follows from the compactness of left edge.

Comment: @Soarer, Aaron: I've added some detail on why I couldn't glue them.

Comment: Do you mean that some part of the left edge is contained in $U_1$ and $U_2$?  I don't think you can assume they contain all of the left edge.  As said above I think you want to start with an open cover of the left edge and show you can paste them together using a compactness argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that I found an answer to my problem. The earlier approach of playing with open covers didn't pan out because I couldn't extend local injectivity of $p$ on a bunch of open sets to injectivity on their union.

But I found the following theorem, which solves the problem quite neatly. I found it in [1], along with a sketch proof. (But I'll prove it fully):

Theorem: Let $E$ be any space and $F$ be a metric space. Let $K\subset E$ be compact, $f:E\to F$ be continuous, locally injective near every point $p\in K$, and (globally) injective on $K$. Then $f$ is also injective on some open neighbourhood $N$ of $K$.

Proof: Let $g:E\times E\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $g(x,x')=d(f(x),f(x'))$. Around each point of the form $(k,k)\in K\times K$, there is an open product neighbourhood $V_k \times V_k$ such that $(V_k\times V_k)\cap g^{-1}(0) \subset \{ (x,x)\in E\times E \}$ (by local injectivity). Let $V=\cup_k \left(V_k\times V_k\right)$. Then the compact set $K\times K$ is contained in
the open set $g^{-1}(0)^c \cup V$. By the generalized tube lemma, there are open sets $W,W'$ of $E$ so that $K\times K\subset W\times W'\subset g^{-1}(0)^c \cup V$. Then let
$N=W\cap W'$. $\square$

Applying this theorem to $p:\tilde{X} \to X$, with $K$ being a lift of the left edge of
$X$, gives an open neighbourhood of that lift which maps homeomorphically to an open
neighbourhood of the left edge of $X$. Then we use the bad local nature of $X$ to find a
loop in $X$ which lifts to a loop in $\tilde{X}$ which is not contractible. (Compactness is used again to find an open set which contains the entirety of a vertical line)

[1] Wagner,M., "Existence of schlicht integral manifolds for ordinary differential equations", Archiv der Mathematik, Volume 61, Number 6, 529-542 (1993)

Comment: This is beautiful! The only thing I would say is that, in using the theorem, you claim that $p$ maps the neighborhood, $N$, of $K$ homeomorphically to an open neighborhood of the left edge. Yes, $p$ will be a continuous bijection from $N$ to its image, but it's not obvious to me that it should be a homeomorphism. If I'm right, this can be fixed by combining this with your original technic: Cover the left edge with $U_i$'s. When you lift $U_i$ to the covering space, choose the copy which intersects $K$ and then intersect it with $N$. Then the union of these will map homeomorphically via $p$.

Comment: I should mention that you can assume WLOG that $U_i\cap(\{0\}\times[0,1])$ is path connected. This is because when you take the original covering of the left edge, you can replace each open set with an open rectangle intersecting the left edge which it contains. Then each $U_i$ will be an open rectangle (intersected with $X$ of course).

Comment: @Anonymous Any covering map is open. So if $p$ maps $N$ bijectively to its image, it will in fact define a homeomorphism from $N$ to its image.

Comment: @CommunicativeAlgebra Ah of course, because $N$ is open, and $p$ is an open map, it follows that if $p\vert_N:N→ p(N)$ is bijective, then it is a homeomorphism. I'm not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that comment. I must have forgotten that covering maps were open and started recreating the proof of it within this problem or something.