# When can I paste together two homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology

Let $p: X\to Y$ and let $U,V$ be open in $X$.
Assume $p$ is a homeomorphism when restricted to $U$ and when restricted to $V$.
Under what conditions is $p$ a homeomorphism on $U\cup V$?

This came up when I was working on [Hatcher 1.3 #5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20634/comb-space-has-no-simply-connected-cover). I don't see why we can paste together local homeomorphisms between the comb space and a covering space to cover the left edge. Especially since the same logic doesn't work with the circle covered by $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

A local homeomorphism may fail to be a homeomorphism by failing to be either injective or surjective. The covering you mention and the inclusion of an open set into, say, the circle, suffice to show that. Now if $p$ is a homeomorphism on $U$ and on $V$, then $p$ must be a homeomorphism on $U\cup V$ unless some point of $U\setminus V$ maps into the image of $V$, or vice versa; indeed, that implication is reversible. That is, you have only to check that the image of $U\setminus V$ is disjoint from the image of $V$ and similarly for the image of $V\setminus U$.

Comment: How can I use this condition to solve the Hatcher problem? I discovered the condition on my own, but still couldn't prove that it applies to the comb space.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be right to me. There are bijective local homeomorphisms that are not homeomorphisms, for instance the map from the real interval $]0, 2\pi]$ to the unit circle defined by $x \mapsto e^{ix}$.

Comment: Well, I just realized there are multiple definitions of local homeomorphism. If one requires $p(U)$ and $p(V)$ to be open subsets of $Y$, then I agree with the answer above.

Comment: @DanieleTurchetti Thanks for this. Yes, I think there's a strong argument for insisting that a local homeomorphism also be locally open in this way, to allow for the equivalence between sheaves over $X$ and local homeomorphisms over $X$. Note that your example does not correspond to a sheaf, as its local sections cannot always be glued.